# F# marshalling of Dictionary<string, object> from deserialized JSON

Tags: json, f#

Within F#, I'm using `JavascriptSerializer.DeserializeObject` to read in a JSON file. That gives me a `Dictionary<string, object>`, and for any such value (which may at runtime be `int`, `string`, `bool`, etc), at compile time, I only know that it's an object.

I know that for my input, certain keys will always have certain types associated with them, but it requires some rather ugly code to translate. For example:

```
// deserialize the text, casting to a dictionary
let parsed = ... :?> Dictionary<string, System.Object>

type MyValue =
    | Scalar of string
    | Array of string[]

// myValue may be either string or string[]
// convert to F# discriminated union of Scalar|Array
let myValue = match parsed.["myValue"] with
    | :? (Object[]) as obj -> Array (obj |> Array.map (fun o -> o :?> string))
    | obj -> Scalar (obj :?> string)
```

Is there a cleaner, possibly safer, more idiomatic way to do this while still using JavascriptSerializer?

Comment: On the side: Don't use `obj` as an identifier; it may work, but it's not good practice, as it's F#'s name for the .NET `object` type. Similarly, `Array` is a name to maybe avoid.

Comment: Don't deserialize into a dictionary. Define a record and deserialize into that.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, is this possible using JavascriptSerializer? If I define a record type, deserialization directly to that F# type can't be done because there's no parameterless constructor for it, which it requires.

Comment: Add `[<CLIMutable>]` to the record. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.climutableattribute-class-%5Bfsharp%5D
to fix the parameterless constructor issue